# create an asymmetric colormap

Tags: python, folium

I am creating a colormap to [map colors](https://github.com/python-visualization/branca/blob/master/branca/colormap.py) in a folium choropleth map, using code from [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb):

```
from branca.colormap import linear

colormap = linear.RdBu.scale(
    df.MyValue.min(),
    df.MyValue.max())

colormap
```

[image: my colormap]

As you can see, the min and max values are skewed compared to the 0, and I'd like this to be reflected in the colormap, i.e. only values < 0 should be mapped to red, while all positive values should be mapped to blue.

Is there a way to have this asymmetry in the colormap? I haven't seen many examples on the web.

I am doing like:

```
colormap = colormap.to_step(index=[-200, 0, 1200])
```

but it's not smooth:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the index if you want an asymmetrical Color Scale (in the documentation is called irregular). Example:

```
import branca.colormap as cm

colormap = cm.LinearColormap(colors=['red','blue'], index=[-200,0],vmin=-200,vmax=1200)
colormap
```

[image]

The transition will be given by your index. For example, these are other transitions:

```
colormap = cm.LinearColormap(colors=['red','blue'], index=[0,200],vmin=-200,vmax=1200)
colormap
```

[image]

Adding a third color:

```
   colormap = cm.LinearColormap(colors=['red','lightblue','blue'], index=[-200,0,1200],vmin=-200,vmax=1200)
    colormap
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MPL has this built-in already with the `TwoSlopeNorm` class: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html?highlight=twoslopenorm#twoslopenorm-different-mapping-on-either-side-of-a-center