# Color Scale markers in Folium Webmaps where Color are based on values. Count of values is approx in 1000's

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a 911 calling details in US. I need to plot web graph using Folium, mark all the coordinates as given in the dataset with Color Scale showing the number of calls made by the respective places(latitude, longitude data).

FYR: I am unable to import folium.colormap. Tried all possibilities

Data Available:
US State info is available in the JSON File extracted from GEOJSON & 911 Calling Data is in *.csv file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=105Zh2mfclHvfAd1nTZjy_7tDquj5OC_1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using folium.colormap, try import branca.colormap.  Here an answer that may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846744/create-an-asymmetric-colormap).

Also, [branca](https://python-visualization.github.io/branca/colormap.html) can do a lot of the same functions that folum.colormap can.